# Apple Developer Connection log-in problems

Tags: authentication, apple-developer

Is there a trick to logging in to Apple Developer Connection? For the past two weeks, out of about 100 tries, I've been able to log in three times. Every other time, after a successful entry of my username and password, it takes me back to the login screen.

This happens to me on both my Macs, on Safari and Firefox, so I'm not hopeful of a solution. But I have a hard time believing that the situation is really this bad...

Comment: This question is not programming related.

Comment: It's not, but it is directly related to programming productivity. And since this is a place where a lot (read: most) iPhone developers hang out, and there's no other appropriate forum for asking the question (the Apple forum that is most appropriate is unavailable due to the problem expressed in this question), it didn't seem wildly off-topic to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, I have narrowed down to a problem with my ISP. Of course they will not acknowledge it, but the problem only arises when I attempt a login from home. I think they are probably using a caching proxy and something in the scheme used by apple to login->access the content makes the proxy believe it's only visiting content that is still valid. I am going slightly mad because of this.

Comment: The solution was related to how our network was configured here at our office. Our IT guy changed something (no idea what, or I'd post it here), and it started working. Still, I blame Apple for this: of all the Internet sites in the world, theirs is the only one that has a problem with our company's network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This question and the related discussion clued me in to how to fix my problem with the same symptoms on developer.apple.com.  In my case, I have multiple "teams," so after entering in my Apple ID, it takes me to a team selection page.  After selecting a team, I'd just be redirected back to the login/Apple ID page.

Turns out, the login is done over HTTPS, while the team selection (and probably the bulk of other activities on developer.apple.com) are over HTTP.  Our firewall load balances over a couple of Internet connections, and the HTTPS traffic was passing over a different interface than the HTTP.  Evidently, this was confusing Apple's authentication mechanism.  It also explains why I was occasionally able to get through -- sometimes all traffic would end up on the same interface.

Ultimately, my solution was to add a rule to the firewall to send all 17.0.0.0/8 traffic (Apple's legacy class A network) over the same interface.

Hopefully this helps someone else with a frustratingly endless login loop.